# VueJS v-else statement rendering multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a little problem with a VueJs app. I have an array with certain dates and another array with some other items fetched from an API that looks like this.

```
const datesArr = [25-09-2020, 26-09-2020, 27-09-2020, 28-10-2020];
```

and the fetched array items which looks like this

```
const fetchedArr = {
  [
    name: "Product 1",
    description: "Lorem ipsum",
    price: 25,
    date: "25-10-2020"
  ],
  [
    name: "Product 2",
    description: "Lorem ipsum",
    price: 35,
    date: "26-10-2020"
  ],
  [
    name: "Product 3",
    description: "Lorem ipsum",
    price: 15,
    date: "28-10-2020"
  ]
}
```

What i want to do is to show for every date from dates array, the tasks from fetched api to it's coresponding date.

This is my vuejs code.

```
<div
   v-for="(day, index) in nextSixDays"
   :key="index"
   >
<div >{{day.day == nextSixDays[0].day ? 'Tomorrow' : day.formatted}}</div>
<div
   v-for="(task, index) in tasks"
   :key="index"
   >
   <div
      v-if="day.day == task.date"
      >
      {{task.name}}
   </div>
   <div v-else>No tasks for this day</div>
</div>
```

And this is the result

[image]

As you see i have 12 tasks which are from the API and if there are some tasks that matches those days from the first array, they are showed, but it is also showing the else statement for the remaining tasks which do not correspond to that day. I want to show it only one time and just for those days which do not have corresponding tasks.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you have 12 tasks, and only 1 is for the current day, then 11 won't be ... so of course you get 11 outputs of v-else, as they don't match the v-if condition

Comment: Do you have any suggestions or a different approach for solving this problem? Thanks!

Comment: what you need to do is a) a computed value (filterdTasks) which filters the `tasks` that match `day.day` ... b) v-if filteredtasks.length == 0 output no tasks c) v-else, for ... in filteredTasks

Comment: @Marc i could do that but i want to show a message that says there are no tasks for that day

Comment: @Chez Don't put the else inside the for loop. Instead add a counter every time there is a match counter goes up by 1. In a separate block, add an `if counter == 0` and render the No tasks for this day there. If you have a task the counter will go up therefore not show the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the following method

```
methods: {
  haveTask(day) {
    return this.tasks.some(task => task.day === day)
  }
}
```

change the markup as follows:

```
<template v-if="haveTask(day.day)">
  <div v-for="(task, index) in tasks" :key="index">
    <div v-if="day.day == task.date">
      {{task.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<div v-else>No tasks for this day</div>
```

There's other, possibly better, ways to achieve this, but this is probably the way with the least amount of changes

You could possibly even do this:

```
<template v-if="tasks.some(task => task.day === day.day)">
```

Without needing to add a method at all

Comment: It is actually working. Thank you a lot @Jaromanda! I really appreciate your help and effort! Thanks again for the help!